# Research on idioms with similar meaning

Tags: idiom-meaning

Could anyone point me to research papers discussing idioms with similar meaning? Are there any algorithms on how to search for a similar idiom?

For example, these idioms are somewhat similar - they all claim that people can't change themselves:

> *Leopard can't change its spots*

This idiom means that people cannot change basic aspects of their character, especially negative ones.

> *In your blood*

A trait or liking that is deeply ingrained in someone's personality and unlikely to change is in their blood.

> *What can you expect from a hog but a grunt?*

This means that you can't expect people to behave in a way that is not in their character- a 'hog' is a 'pig', so an unrefined person can't be expected to behave in a refined way.

Comment: Check out Lakoff and Johnson, _Metaphors We Live By_. All of these are metaphors; many if not most idioms have metaphors behind/beneath/powering them.

Comment: These are _aphorisms_: a pithy observation that contains a general truth.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any source where you can input a "general truth" and get bunch of idioms/metaphors/aphorisms supporting this truth? This would be very handy..

Comment: The study of proverbs is called [paremiology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paremiology). Though I haven't heard of an online webapp that does what you suggest, it sounds like it might be possible with current ontology development. Without such a convenient app built for you, asking one by one on ELU is probably the best bet given that there are a number of translation/meaning requests here for proverbs.

Comment: I would argue that your above three examples are not that close in meaning.

Comment: I agree that they are only "somewhat" similar, they are here just for illustration. Thanks to everyone for enlightening me!

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily an algorithm, but a way of looking for idioms which have similar meaning would be to visit idiom dictionaries like [TheFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/search), [Idioms4You](http://www.idioms4you.com/find-idioms.html), and [IdiomCorner](http://idiomcorner.com/). The latter 2 have neat tagging systems which will help you navigate through the database so you can search for similar idioms.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, these dictionaries give you a way to search idioms by keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You need Barron's Educational Series, available from your favourite online monster book store. Such titles as "Spanish and English Idioms". I have the Franch one as well. Don't know how big the series is.
[http://www.amazon.com/German-Idioms-Barrons-Series/dp/0764143832/ref=pd_sim_14_6?ie=UTF8&refRID=0ZYZN2BSYD5FHAXAAVJR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764143832)